# Python: Inconsistent results with urlopen

Tags: python, html, web-crawler, urllib2

I'm using `urlopen` function from `urllib2` and I'm different results every time when reading the same page. Code:

```
import urllib2
for i in range(5):
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://wlstorage.net/file/freddy-balzan-emails-2005-2008/')
    html = response.read()
    print len(html), 'first chars:', html[:10] ,'last chars:', html[-10:]
```

Output:

```
zvi@zvi-S400CA:~/workspace/crawler$ python mini_test.py 
14259 first chars: <!-- MHonA last chars: E1;n</em> 
15707 first chars: <!-- MHonA last chars: 5, 2008)<b
43219 first chars: <!-- MHonA last chars: ="07081" h
37427 first chars: <!-- MHonA last chars: 01.html">F
43219 first chars: <!-- MHonA last chars: ="07081" h
```

What is causing that and how can I fix it such that I will obtain the entire page and not just a fraction of it?

Comment: Maybe there is dynamic content on the page whose size changes each time. For example, different advertisements may take up different amounts of space. In which case, the answer is "there's nothing to fix"

Comment: The specific web page in my example doesn't have any advertisements and it's content seems static.

Comment: Try inspecting the `html` value in addition to looking at its length. For example, does it always end with "</html>"?

Comment: The page contains 400 links to mails which I extract using a regex, but most of the times it returns much less than 400. THe result of the regex should be deterministic and it means that not all 400 links are retrieved with urlopen, but I guarantee you that each time you open this page manually you will see 400 links

Comment: Done, I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://wlstorage.net/file/freddy-balzan-emails-2005-2008/')
>>> len(response.text)
68361
```